# FTP server with a 50Mb connection

Tags: ftp, internet, performance

We are moving our FTP server to a data center, which will have a 50Mb pipe to the internet.  Will our customers see a an increase in file upload speed once we have moved?  What is unclear to me is if our clients are uploading data from their prospective connection then how will our 50Mb connection be relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on several factors:

- Is the 50mbit/s connection symmetrical (50mbit up and 50mbit down)?
- How much bandwith does the customer have? If the customer have a 1mbit/s connection it won't matter how much bandwith your FTP server have, unless you have more than 50 concurrent users where all of them use 1mbit/s.

Comment: One other thing to add is that the 50/mbit connection might have lower latency. Although Higher bandwidth != lower latency, I bet higher bandwidth connections generally do have lower latency -- at least when comes to something like DSL compared to a data center pipe.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends how congested your current connection was.  If transfers were maxing the connection out fairly regularly, then yes the extra bandwidth will be noticable, but if they were not, then no there will be no noticable difference.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way.

Say you have a 10 MB connection now, and each customer has a 1 MB connection.

If you have 10 customers all using the connection you will be maxed out and each customer will be able to use all of their bandwidth.  If you have 20 customers using your 10 MB connection then each customer, in theory, will only have .5 MB available to them.

Obviously, that's a pretty simplified answer, but it should explain things for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your original pipe speed was, how many concurrent sessions you have coming into your pipe (ie- were you pegged with your original connection) and, yes, what their pipe speeds are.  As in anything your bottleneck will be the slowest pipe (or worst route if there's big problems somewhere).  In general your customers who are on slower pipes than your original connection won't notice much, if any, improvement.  Others with bigger pipes might notice some slight improvement.